# How to set physical path to upload a file in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I want to upload a file in a physical path such as **`E:\Project\Folders`**.

I got the below code by searching in the net.

```
//check to make sure a file is selected
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    //create the path to save the file to
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), FileUpload1.FileName);
    //save the file to our local path
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);
}
```

But in that, I want to give my physical path as I mentioned above. How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Server.MapPath("~/Files")` returns an absolute path based on a folder relative to your application. The leading `~/` tells ASP.Net to look at the root of your application.

To use a folder outside of the application:

```
//check to make sure a file is selected
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    //create the path to save the file to
    string fileName = Path.Combine(@"E:\Project\Folders", FileUpload1.FileName);
    //save the file to our local path
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);
}
```

Of course, you wouldn't hardcode the path in a production application but this should save the file using the absolute path you described.

With regards to locating the file once you have saved it (per comments):

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(@"E:\Project\Folders", FileUpload1.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);

    FileInfo fileToDownload = new FileInfo( filename ); 

    if (fileToDownload.Exists){ 
        Process.Start(fileToDownload.FullName);
    }
    else { 
        MessageBox("File Not Saved!"); 
        return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It is working fine in my application. But I hosted the application in the local IIS. I can save the file but could not retrieve the saved file. why this is happening? How to solve this?

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the file? Are you able to browse to it in Windows explorer?

Comment: I have used the below code: I can retrieve by running the application. But after publishing it in my local host, I cant retrieve. string FilePath = Path.Combine(@"E:\Project\Folders\");
        FileInfo fileToDownload = new FileInfo(FilePath + "\\" + filename);
        if (fileToDownload.Exists)
            Process.Start(fileToDownload.FullName);
        else
        {
            MessageBox("File Not Saved!");
            return;
        }

Comment: thank for ur effort. I followed ur steps but I couldn't retrieve the file after hosting it. The same thing is happening again. Any way thank u so much for ur answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

you can accomplish this by using the [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms150160.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Fileupload1 is ID of Upload file
if (Fileupload1.HasFile)
{
    // Take one variable 'save' for store Destination folder path with file name
    var save = Server.MapPath("~/Demo_Images/" + Fileupload1.FileName);
    Fileupload1.SaveAs(save);
}
```