# How to select Default folder location in File Upload Control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to set the default path folder location has to be opened, Once I press the "browse" button in File Control. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1273605.aspx) forum says it can't be done.

> You are wanting to control the directory location that the browse
>   starts in and not the save path the file is uploaded to, correct?
>
> I could be wrong but since the server never knows the file structure
>   of the client machine, the developers of that control probably did not
>   provide for that functionality.

Answer (score -1):

COPIED: [How to set physical path to upload a file in Asp.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479942/how-to-set-physical-path-to-upload-a-file-in-asp-net)

To use a folder outside of the application:

```
//check to make sure a file is selected
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    //create the path to save the file to
    string fileName = Path.Combine(@"E:\Project\Folders", FileUpload1.FileName);
    //save the file to our local path
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);
}
```

Of course, you wouldn't hardcode the path in a production application but this should save the file using the absolute path you described.

With regards to locating the file once you have saved it (per comments):

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(@"E:\Project\Folders", FileUpload1.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);

    FileInfo fileToDownload = new FileInfo( filename ); 

    if (fileToDownload.Exists){ 
        Process.Start(fileToDownload.FullName);
    }
    else { 
        MessageBox("File Not Saved!"); 
        return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about how to set the default path to be *opened*, not to be *saved*.